# Does there exist a subspace $W\subseteq M_{4\times 4} (\mathbb{R})$, such that the length of the orthogonal projection of a certain matrix is 5?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A= \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & -1 & 1 & -1 \\
-1 & 1 & -1 & 1 \\
1 & -1 & 1 & -1 \\
-1 & 1 & -1 & 1 \\
\end{array} \right) $ a matrix in $M_{4\times 4}(\mathbb{R})$. Does there exist a subspace $W\subseteq M_{4\times 4}(\mathbb{R})$, such that the length of the orthogonal projection of $A$ on $W$ is 5? This is when the inner product is $(A,B)=tr(B^{t}A)$.

I tried to disprove it by writing $A=B_{1}+B_{2} $, when $B_{1}\in W$, and $B_{2}\in W^{\perp} $. We're trying to figure out if $(B_1,B_1)=25$. I also wrote $(B_1,B_1)=(B_1, A-B_2)=(B_1,A)$, but that didn't get me far. I also calculated $(B_1, B_1) $, but also didn't yield any results.

I'd like a direction on this, hopefully something that doesn't require too much calculating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Denote that $\Vert B\Vert=\sqrt{(B,B)}=\sqrt{{\rm tr}(B^tB)}$ for any
$4\times 4$ real matrix $B$. Now,
given a subspace $W\subseteq M_{4\times 4}(\mathbb{R})$, write
$A=B_1+B_2$, where $B_1\in W$ and $B_2\in W^\perp$. Then
\begin{align*}
16=\Vert A\Vert^2=\Vert B_1+B_2\Vert^2
  =\Vert B_1\Vert^2+2(B_1,B_2)+\Vert B_2\Vert^2
  =\Vert B_1\Vert^2+\Vert B_2\Vert^2,
\end{align*}
which shows that $\Vert B_1\Vert^2\leq 16<25$ or $\Vert B_1\Vert<5$.